# Cross-Table SQL Query

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to make a cross table query between the tables student and test. I want to select the student first name, student last name, test result, test date and test type for a specific student that the teacher has chosen. Since I have 'StudentID' in both tables I thought having a where clause would be sufficient.

I have test the following code, which WORKS but does not do what I want. When the student types the studentID e.g.3. Instead of getting all the columns for student with studentID 3, the output is blank. [nothing].

C# Code:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT student.studentFirstName, student.studentLastName, test.test_date, test.test_type, test.test_results FROM student, test WHERE (student.studentID AND test.testID = '" + Convert.ToInt32(txtBoxID.Text) + "');");
```

IF I am using the wrong query, which query should I be using?

Thank you.

I have found the answer to this question on w3School:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT test.test_date, test.test_type, test.test_results, student.studentFirstName, student.studentLastName FROM test INNER JOIN student ON test.studentID = student.studentID WHERE test.studentID = '" + txtBoxID.Text + "';");
```

Comment: Please use parameters for your query to prevent from SQL injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `join` to get the records with `StudentID` as joining column, e.g.:

```
SELECT s.studentFirstName, s. studentLastName, t.test_date, t.test_type, t.test_results
FROM student s JOIN test t ON s.StudentID = t.StudentID
WHERE t.StudentID = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT student.studentFirstName, student.studentLastName, test.test_date, test.test_type, test.test_results FROM student, test WHERE (student.studentID AND test.studentID = '" + Convert.ToInt32(txtBoxID.Text) + "');");
```

just change *test.testID* to *test.studentID*